# Why are isotherms skewed to 45 degrees in the tephigram?

Tags: atmosphere, climate

I have studied about tephigrams. In all the books, it has written that isotherms and dry adiabats are skewed to certain degrees. But practically I could not connect it. How is it possible that constant temperatures and dry adiabats as well as dew points are skewed? Please explain it.

Comment: Have you had a look at a tephigram/Skew-T log-P diagram? Have you had a look at the connection between the values you mention?

Comment: Yes I have gone through actual tephigram and skew T diagram. Due to too much complexity, I am confused.

Comment: Do you know, how the different units presented (temperature, pressure, moisture) are interconnected?

Comment: Yes, but I can't figure out how isotherms (costant temp.) are vertically skwed. Actually horizontal isoterms are easily comprehensible. The doubt doubles, when I have read on a website Skew T diagram are intentionally skwed to seperate out dew point and pressure lines. I could not really connect it. And my concept that had gathered from Berry and  Chorley written book got scattered.